# How to do some constraint checking during knex/objectionjs raw query

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js, objection.js

I am doing some raw query binding in objectionjs and my code is as follows:

```js
const item = await cart.$relatedQuery('items').insert(req.body)
            .onConflict(['cartId', 'productId'])
            .merge({
                amount: raw('cart_item.amount + ?', req.body.amount),
                price: raw('cart_item.price + ?', req.body.price)
            });
```

Values for `req.body.amount` and `req.body.price` can be both positive and negative. Because of this, at some point the final value for `amount` and `price` fields in the database might become negative too after the addition/subtraction. And I want to prevent that from happening. What should I do in such case?

I tried the following:

```js
amount: Math.max(raw('cart_item.amount + ?', req.body.amount), 0)
```

But this doesn't work (of course it shouldn't) and returns NaN. I don't want to put an `.unsigned()` check on the field itself, but check during runtime. Is there any way I can get what I want without making multiple queries to fetch the values for `amount` and `price` beforehand and checking before inserting the new values?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
amount: raw('cart_item.amount + ?', ((cart_item.amount + req.body.amount) >= 0) ? req.body.amount : 0 ),
```

Comment: that will run, but it won't achieve what I want. If `req.body.amount` is `-10`, and `amount` field's value is `20`, then final value `20-10 = 10` is greater than 0. I want to keep it as it is this time.

Comment: @skylark is there a way to reference the `amount` field value inline?

Comment: hey I was able to do it in the following way, but it seems nasty and not good. I will wait to see if there's any better way. And I don't actually know if amount field's value can be referenced as I want. There's a [ref()](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/objection/#ref) function, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.
`amount: raw('case when cart_item.amount + ? < 0 then 0 else cart_item.amount + ? end', [req.body.amount, req.body.amount])`

Answer (score 0):

the way i would do it at runtime is using [transactions](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/guide/transactions.html#using-a-transaction):

```
const trx = await Item.startTransaction()

try {
    const item = await cart
        .$relatedQuery('items', trx) // make sure to pass the transaction
        .insert(req.body)
        .onConflict(['cartId', 'productId'])
        .merge({
            amount: raw('cart_item.amount + ?', req.body.amount),
            price: raw('cart_item.price + ?', req.body.price)
        });

    if (item.price < 0 || item.amount < 0 ) {
        // this will trigger the catch block and revert the operation
        throw new Error(...)
    }
    // success return as response or something
    res.json(item)

    await trx.commit()
} catch (err) {
    await trx.rollback()
    return next(err)
}
```